# How to create IPAddr-object with a netmask

Tags: ruby

I just tried to use Ruby's [IPAddr](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class and I've been wondering if it is possible to create a new IPAddr with a netmask. To clarify my issue this is what I've done:

```
IPAddr.new "192.186.2.253/24"
=> #<IPAddr: IPv4:192.186.2.0/255.255.255.0>
```

What I would expect is to get this:

```
#<IPAddr: IPv4:192.186.2.253/255.255.255.0>
```

If I use the `to_range` method, the ip addresses are matching the second example.

Did i get anything wrong with this class? How can I achieve to initialize such an ip address without cutting off the host id.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a netmask is supplied, the address is treated as a network address, not a host address, at least that's how I interpret your findings in combination with [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-c-new):

> If a prefixlen or a mask is specified, it returns a **masked IP address**.

I assume, by "masked IP address", the author means a network address, at least that's what makes the most sense given the behavior you observed and the [description of the `IPAddr#to_range` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-to_range).